# High availability setup to prevent major outages on cloud providers

Tags: networking, dns

I have a quite common setup to deliver content: The DNS A records point to a gateway server which NAT's the expected requests to a webserver, which pulls information from a DB-Server. All of this is hosted on a cloud provider, web and db server are in a private network not directly accessible from the internet.
Now the cloud provider had a major outage which took down the application.

Which possibilities do I have to make the whole thing redundant?
First thought was cloning the same setup to another cloud provider, syncing the DB and putting a fallback ip into the DNS A record, but it seems this is only a thing for MX records.
Second thought was monitoring the availability of the tier 1 setup and triggering a DNS record change if it goes down, but propagation can take time and DNS-caching will cause problems.

**Is there a possibility to build this without a single point of failure?** What is the best practice for high availability in settings like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your budget?  You have essentially the following options.

1. Get an anycast IP.  The anycast IP can route to the closest available front end.  You only need one A record, and any failover is quick.  Disadvantage: this is expensive and complicated to configure.
2. DNS with filter chains.  This adjusts the A records based on front-end availability.  As noted in your question, there is a propagation time, which you can control to some extent via the record's TTL.  But this would be the most common approach unless you have a healthy budget.

There are numerous variations on the above.  For example, you can have multiple A records and disable those corresponding to a front-end that is down - this will still involve a propagation delay, but there's at least some random chance that a client will use the 'good' A record.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am interested in all options, independent of budget. I will look into anycast IP.